# Google Map problems

Tags: javascript, google-maps

i am trying to display google map in contact us page,do not know what is the actual problem it is not displaying, below is my code

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places">

    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success);
    } else {
        alert("Geo Location is not supported on your current browser!");
    }
    function success(position) {
        var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
        var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
        var city = position.coords.locality;
        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
        var myOptions = {
            center: myLatlng,
            zoom: 12,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatlng,
            title: "lat: " + latitude + " long: " + longitude
        });

        marker.setMap(map);
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ content: "<b>User Address</b><br/> Latitude:" + latitude + "<br /> Longitude:" + longitude + "" });
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    </script>
```

please help

Comment: What errors are there in the console, if any?

Comment: actually problem is, it is showing no error but map is not visible

Comment: i think problem in calling javacript function

Comment: Try what Duncan has suggested. Also show us how are you calling "success" method.

Comment: hello ankit, i am calling success method in body tag like this, onload="success(51.508742)" i think it is wrong way is'nt it

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success);
} else {
    alert("Geo Location is not supported on your current browser!");
}
.....
</script>
```

Please use like above code, it is solving your issues.

Answer (score 0):

Mayur's suggestion is good.  But you also have a missing closing } at the end of your function.  Try this:

```
function success(position) {
        var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
        var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
        var myOptions = {
            center: myLatlng,
            zoom: 12,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatlng,
            title: "lat: " + latitude + " long: " + longitude
        });

        marker.setMap(map);
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ content: "<b>User Address</b><br/> Latitude:" + latitude + "<br /> Longitude:" + longitude });
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
}
```

You also don't need to do `+ ""` at the end of your infowindow content.  I've also removed the unused variable `city`

Comment: thanks will you please tell me how to call this function, actualy i think i am calling in wrong way